# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, oozie

I am running spark job in oozie by using shell action but spark task is not lunching. Job is stuck and only lunching below task

[image]

```
2018-10-23 09:20:31,021 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:21:01,059 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:21:31,129 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:22:01,165 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:22:31,202 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:23:01,238 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:23:31,275 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:24:01,362 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:24:31,400 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:25:01,435 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:25:31,472 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:26:01,572 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:26:31,607 INFO [IPC Server handler 3 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:27:01,644 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:27:31,680 INFO [IPC Server handler 10 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:28:01,721 INFO [IPC Server handler 26 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:28:31,803 INFO [IPC Server handler 9 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2018-10-23 09:29:01,839 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 32995] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1537255103946_84288_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
```